# Add array elements separated by comma at run time - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I am using an API which requires me to use the below function:

```
out.writeNext(trtd[0], trtd[1], trtd[2]);
```

As you may guess from the code, the array elements can only be separated by comma. I may know the length of the trtd array but how do I dynamically add more elements as arguments? So that the code can be varied for n elements (as we can't do a for loop here when arguments vary and need separation by comma).

```
out.writeNext(trtd[0], trtd[1], trtd[2],.........,trtd[n]);
```

I thought of getting the arguments in a string and then converting that to code but I tried different methods didn't work for me. Please help me with answers.

Comment: What API is it that could possibly have this restriction? Could you not simply call writeNext for each element of the array?

Comment: No it would perform some other operation. I need to take the arguments together and the Library I am trying to use is OpenCSV

Comment: Are you sure you can't just pass the array itself?  The method signature looks close to a [`Varargs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html) signature, which can accept either a comma-delimited list of elements, or an actual array.

Comment: Can't you use a for loop and add with the index.

Comment: I cannot pass the array itself.

Comment: I cannot use a loop as the function needs input of all arguments at once.

Comment: @AbhishekSingh according the [parent project docs](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/index.html), it does accept a `String[]`.  I'm almost positive that you can pass the array itself.  Have you really tried passing the array itself?  If you can't, find a better version of the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"writeNext" method is like at the below([Link](http://opencsv.googlecode.com/hg-history/91bf7f3b51ca359d1b044d3f63f21146d02f5418/doc/api/au/com/bytecode/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#writeNext%28java.lang.String...%29));

```
public void writeNext(java.lang.String... nextLine)
```

So you can pass your all parameter via;

```
out.writeNext(trtd);
```

Because "trtd" is string array. "`someMethod(String... str)`" means you can pass parameters as "`someMethod("a", "b", "c");`" or you can pass string array as; `String [] arr= {"a", "b", "c"}`; -> "`someMethod(arr);`"

Comment: Yes it works. I hope I don't get such problem where I can't use loops like above. For API, yes this is perfect answer. Thanks!